# Datatables vertical scroll with hidden rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and have hidden certain rows using jQuery .toggle() which basically just adds a "display: none" to the element in question.  I have hidden rows and my table's vertical scroll does not recalculate the length of the table based on what is visibile and what is not.  So after the last visible element, there is empty space where the rows used to be that can still be scrolled.

I am looking for a way to recalculate table scroll height based off of what is visible.

Here is an image of the issue, I don't want this empty space to be there. [image]

It should look like this[image]

Initialization Code:

`g_oTable = $('#' + tableName).DataTable({
        colReorder: true
        , rowId: 'alertid'
        , searchHighlight: true
        , stateSave: true
        , stateDuration: -1 
        , autoWidth: false
        , order: [
            [0, "asc"], [5, "desc"]
        ]
        , info: true
        , scroller: true
        , scrollX: false
        , scrollY: ($(window).height() - 215)
        , scrollCollapse: true
        , deferRender: false
        , rowGroup: {
            enable: false,
            startRender: function ( rows, group ) {
                return '<span class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="margin-
                    left:5px;margin-right:10px;"aria-hidden="true"></span>' 
                    + group +' ('+rows.count()+')';
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.  In my initialization, I was using scroller and I have no documentation or reasoning for it's incompatibility with my use case, but using `scroller: false` helped fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the code below every time you toggle visibility of certain rows.

```
$.fn.dataTable
    .tables( { visible: true, api: true } )
    .scroller.measure();
```

Comment: I hadn't come across this method before, but it didn't change the behavior when I added it.  I confirmed that the drawCallback was being called, so the code you gave was definitely calling a redraw, just didn't take care of the empty space issue

Comment: @justinlav, please show your DataTables initialization code. Also please try using [`scrollCollapse: true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollCollapse) initialization option.

Comment: I added the initialization code to the question.  I left out the ajax call and some click handlers as the issue only occurs when I attempt to collapse rowGroups after I enable Rowgroup on button click. I am currently using scrollCollapse: true, this behavior is very strange. As far as I know, Datatables should be able to automatically clear the empty space based on the visibility of rows.